# IF statement inside .click / .on('click') not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't get why this isn't working.. `clickId` is given the value `access-toggle-all`, when I click the checkbox with that classname, so it doesn't make sense (to me at least)..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:checkbox').click(function (e) {
        var clickId = $(this).attr('class');

        if (clickId == 'access-toggle-all') {
            alert("if");
            $('.access-toggle,.access-group-toggle').prop('checked', this.checked);
        } else {
            alert("else");
        }

        alert(clickId);
    });
});
```

Comment: Use .hasClass("access-toggle-all") instead of .attr('class'). What if there are two classes on the same element. :)

Comment: What has this qeustion to do with wicket?

Comment: @RobertNiestroj I use Java and Wicket, and Wicket messed up the jQuery script. So there you go.

Comment: @MaheshSapkal All my classes consist of multiple classes. So using `.hasClass` is not an option. I get the classes and remove the parts of the string that isn't needed.

Comment: There is no indication that this is in any way wicket or java related except for your comment that you use java and that wicket magically messed up your JS. If it's wicket related, show some wicket code related to this 'mess up'.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what your issue was, but it was not your use of single or double quotes unless they were inconsistent opening and closing quotes.

I suspect it was something to do with the element being clicked having more than just the class `access-toggle-all` so this comparison failed:

```
if (clickId == 'access-toggle-all') {
```

The correct way to do this logic using jquery is with `.is()` or `hasClass()`:

```
 $('input:checkbox').click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).is('.access-toggle-all')) {
        alert("if");
        $('.access-toggle,.access-group-toggle').prop('checked', this.checked);
    }
});
```

or

```
 $('input:checkbox').click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('access-toggle-all')) {
        alert("if");
        $('.access-toggle,.access-group-toggle').prop('checked', this.checked);
    } 
});
```

Comment: You were right. The quotation marks had nothing to do with it. Wicket on the other hand... I know that is a "better way" of doing it, but my code example is just a starting point.